How to match values to defined bins in another data frame and extract specific information?
So I have two data frames. I'm trying to use smps_8 as the particle value that I am trying to find on the smps_7 for each of the different days. For example, in smps_8, the column c2014-09-30 19:00:00 equals 11.81 particles. I want to go to smps_7 and look at the same column, c2014-09-30 19:00:00, to match the particles in that bin by finding the diameter size, which is 631. Another example would be the c2014-09-30 23:00:00,, and when I compare both smps_7 and smps_8, the diameter is 562.00. I have been lost on how to execute this code to get my results. I would gladly appreciate assistance or guidance.
smps_11 <- for (k in 1:51) { 
  for (i in 1:3) {
    (smps_7[, k] == smps_8[, i]) 
  }
}

smps_12 <- as.data.frame(smps_11) 

data
> dput(smps_7)
structure(list(`c2014-09-30 19:00:00` = c(0.548908333333333, 
1.2157325, 2.65529583333333, 5.74850916666667, 12.0445341666667, 
24.4163758333333, 64.5522591666667, 176.366434166667, 389.4417675, 
703.5405175, 1058.70135083333, 1382.4262675, 1643.87360083333, 
1848.0287675, 2014.56168416667, 2125.3810675, 2230.84120083333, 
2327.64333416667, 2420.93942583333, 2524.28760916667, 2629.28030916667, 
2778.07320916667, 3005.2465425, 3370.94795916667, 3945.5402925, 
4687.92712583333, 5509.4920425, 6370.0917925, 7218.18962583333, 
7988.00137583333, 8740.34370916667, 9445.1875425, 10111.7412091667, 
10799.3267925, 11617.4886258333, 13020.3669591667, 15236.9852925, 
15251.0852925, 18156.5586258333, 20281.0019591667, 21953.3437925, 
23196.4887925, 23868.9383758333, 24200.2703508333, 24333.0681541667, 
24431.3255458333, 24501.8296125, 24554.4242458333, 24611.2986375, 
24660.4229208333, 24722.7393958333), `c2014-09-30 21:00:00` = c(0.782695, 
1.96499333333333, 3.63771833333333, 6.52546083333333, 11.8135525, 
21.0331625, 63.7110125, 167.403279166667, 365.927945833333, 671.900445833333, 
1025.00927916667, 1361.31144583333, 1660.3496125, 1912.04519583333, 
2115.56419583333, 2283.29427916667, 2442.4041125, 2592.8683625, 
2744.1208625, 2913.95102916667, 3108.39019583333, 3374.01802916667, 
3773.2768625, 4361.34052916667, 5161.3113625, 6054.96069583333, 
6958.5768625, 8040.45152916667, 9535.84652916667, 11602.5923625, 
13488.1498625, 15127.0356958333, 16526.6431958333, 17904.9540291667, 
19733.5006958333, 22437.9623625, 26172.0206958333, 26186.1206958333, 
29265.9840291667, 31831.8390291667, 33509.9065291667, 34355.3470291667, 
34802.9641125, 35011.2177625, 35078.4591625, 35113.2847541667, 
35124.9549708333, 35126.9018208333, 35126.9018208333, 35143.4336541667, 
35146.0820541667), `c2014-09-30 23:00:00` = c(0.551944166666667, 
1.100145, 2.31581416666667, 4.809935, 9.66305333333333, 19.1470975, 
56.1960641666667, 159.372139166667, 348.4962225, 621.0039725, 
944.1162225, 1248.39155583333, 1521.5977225, 1758.52480583333, 
1963.09388916667, 2165.46805583333, 2360.00280583333, 2556.23588916667, 
2750.84763916667, 2935.35238916667, 3141.82288916667, 3424.93405583333, 
3874.56055583333, 4549.3247225, 5444.69088916667, 6397.5654725, 
7532.51713916667, 8986.9579725, 10686.2254725, 12325.0438058333, 
14026.0379725, 16239.5813058333, 19563.2963058333, 24312.7179725, 
30299.4421391667, 35871.9921391667, 40182.1846391667, 40196.2846391667, 
42450.4996391667, 43617.1341391667, 44334.6965558333, 44757.4907225, 
44981.5782058333, 45090.8732891667, 45137.2322025, 45161.9947108333, 
45170.9343858333, 45172.4257275, 45172.4257275, 45240.0353941667, 
45250.8664941667), Diameter = c(1000, 891, 794, 708, 631, 562, 
501, 447, 398, 355, 316, 282, 251, 224, 200, 178, 158, 141, 126, 
112, 100, 89.1, 79.4, 70.8, 63.1, 56.2, 50.1, 44.7, 39.8, 35.5, 
31.6, 28.2, 25.1, 22.4, 20, 17.8, 15.8, 14.1, 12.6, 11.2, 10, 
8.91, 7.94, 7.08, 6.31, 5.62, 5.01, 4.47, 3.98, 3.61, 3.55)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("d1000", 
"d891", "d794", "d708", "d631", "d562", "d501", "d447", "d398", 
"d355", "d316", "d282", "d251", "d224", "d200", "d178", "d158", 
"d141", "d126", "d112", "d100", "d89.1", "d79.4", "d70.8", "d63.1", 
"d56.2", "d50.1", "d44.7", "d39.8", "d35.5", "d31.6", "d28.2", 
"d25.1", "d22.4", "d20", "d17.8", "d15.8", "d14.1", "d12.6", 
"d11.2", "d10", "d8.91", "d7.94", "d7.08", "d6.31", "d5.62", 
"d5.01", "d4.47", "d3.98", "d3.61", "d3.55"))

> dput(smps_8)
structure(list(`c2014-09-30 19:00:00` = 11.81, `c2014-09-30 21:00:00` = 11.42, 
    `c2014-09-30 23:00:00` = 11.51), class = "data.frame", row.names = "concSS5")


If I understand correctly, smps_7 is a data frame of bins for each time, and you want to find the bins, in which the values of smps_8 for each time would fall.
If you just need the Diameters, you want the first bin, that the value exceeds, and may do
> res <- numeric(length=ncol(smps_8))
> for (i in seq_along(smps_8)) {
+   bin <- which.min(smps_8[, i] >= smps_7[, i])
+   res[[i]] <- smps_7[bin, 'Diameter']
+ }
> res
[1] 631 631 562

If you also want the bin's (row-)names, try
> res <- vector(mode='list', length=length(ncol(smps_8)))
> for (i in seq_along(smps_8)) {
+   bin <- which.min(smps_8[, i] >= smps_7[, i])
+   res[[i]] <- smps_7[bin, 'Diameter', drop=FALSE]
+ }
> do.call('rbind', res)
      Diameter
d631       631
d6311      631
d562       562


If you need to join by floating point values, I suggest you use overlap joins with a small added buffer, e.g.
> buffer <- 0.05
> smps_8 |> 
+     rownames_to_column() |> 
+     pivot_longer(-rowname) |> 
+     inner_join(
+         smps_7 |> 
+             pivot_longer(-Diameter) |> 
+             mutate(value_lower = value - buffer, value_upper = value + buffer) |> 
+             rename(value_center = value),
+         join_by(name, between(value, value_lower, value_upper))
+     )
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  rowname name                 value Diameter value_center value_lower value_upper
  <chr>   <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 concSS5 c2014-09-30 21:00:00 11.81      631      11.8136     11.7636     11.8636

This is assuming smps_8$`c2014-09-30 21:00:00`  equals to 11.81 (and not 19:00:00 as in the original dput)
